# Javascript if statement conditions not met?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, if-statement

i'm sure this is a stupid logic error but I've been unable to see what i've done wrong.  while using any values besides 1024 the correct if statement fires, for some reason, the 1024 condition isn't met.  thanks in advance!

```
var width = 1024; //screen.width;
var height = 768; //screen.height;
var subpageModifier;

if (width > 360 && width < 767) {
    subpageModifier = .28;
};
if( width > 767 && width < 800){
    subpageModifier = 0.15;
};
if (width > 800 && width < 961) {
    subpageModifier = .15;
}; 
if (width > 961 &&  width >1135){
    subpageModifier = 0.3;
};
if (width >1135 && width < 1535){
    subpageModifier = 0.15;
};
```

Note: I'm using AngularJS if that helps

Comment: Why not chain these in an `else-if`?

Comment: Typo here: `width >1135`. Incidentally, if your value is exactly `767`, `800`, etc, none of these will work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(width > 961 &&  width >1135)
```

Second `>` should be `<`.

```
(width > 961 &&  width <1135)
```

PS: Use `if-else`, there is no need to check every condition if you found the match

Answer (score 2):

```
if (width > 961 &&  width >1135){
    subpageModifier = 0.3;
};
```

should be less than 1135:

```
if (width > 961 &&  width < 1135){
    subpageModifier = 0.3;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
if (width > 961 &&  width >1135){
```

Use:

```
if (width > 961 &&  width < 1135){
```

Ideally everything should be:

```
var width = 1024; //screen.width;
var height = 768; //screen.height;
var subpageModifier;

if (width >= 360 && width <= 767) {
    subpageModifier = .28;
}else if( width > 767 && width <= 800){
    subpageModifier = 0.15;
}else if (width > 800 && width <= 961) {
    subpageModifier = .15;
}else if (width > 961 &&  width <= 1135){
    subpageModifier = 0.3;
}else if (width >1135 && width <= 1535){
    subpageModifier = 0.15;
}else{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: You don't need to check lower bound if you just checked it as an upper bound in a case above.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 updates.

1. there should be no semi-colon after if statements.
2. You should use if-else for the above conditions.
3. Your `if (width > 961 &&  width >1135){`has a problem with second condition.

Answer (score 1):

Here's your problem:

```
if (width > 961 &&  width > 1135){
    subpageModifier = 0.3;
};
```

Both are > symbols